# MySQL Insert 20K rows in single insert

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

In my table I insert around 20,000 rows on each load. Right now I am doing it one-by-one. From mysql website I came to know inserting multiple rows with single insert query is faster.

Can I insert all 20000 in single query?

What will happen if there are errors within this 20000 rows? how will mysql handle that?

Comment: "From mysql website I came to know inserting multiple rows with single insert query is faster." - where is the source?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are inserting the rows from some other table then you can use the **[INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)** pattern to insert the rows.

However if you are inserting the values using `INSERT ... VALUES` pattern then you have the limit of  max_allowed_packet.

Also from the docs:-

> To optimize insert speed, combine many small operations into a single
>   large operation. Ideally, you make a single connection, send the data
>   for many new rows at once, and delay all index updates and consistency
>   checking until the very end.

Example:-

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ("d1", "d2"),
                                                 ("d1", "d2"),
                                                 ("d1", "d2"),
                                                 ("d1", "d2"),
                                                 ("d1", "d2");
```

> What will happen if there are errors within this 20000 rows?

If there are errors while inserting the records then the operation will be aborted.

Comment: The whole insert will be aborted? or from the point it fails ?

Comment: In that case what is the best way to know like how many rows were inserted, if there was an error ?

Comment: @user3360140 as one of the options is to check logs in case of errors

Answer (score 4):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

You can use code to generate the insert `VALUES` section based on your data source.

**Errors:** if there are errors in the `INSERT` statement (including in any of the rows) the operation will be aborted.

Generating the query - this will be based on your data source, for example, if you are getting data from an associative array in PHP, you'll do something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (a, b, c) VALUES ";
foreach($dataset as $row)
{
    $sql .= "(" + $row['a'] + ", "  + $row['a'] + ", "  + $row['a'] + ")";
    // OR
    $sql .= "($row[a], $row[b], $row[c])";
}
```

Some more resources:

[Optimize MySQL Queries – Fast Inserts With Multiple Rows](http://blog.cnizz.com/2010/05/31/optimize-mysql-queries-fast-mutliple-row-inserts/)

[The fastest way to insert 100K records](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/04/fastest-way-to-insert-100k-registers.html)

Comment: Remember to sanitize your data ;).

Answer (score 2):

batch insert with SQL: insert into table (col...coln) values (col... coln),(col...coln)... but the SQL length is limited by 1M default,  you can change  max_allowed_packet parameter to support more bigger single insert