# Bulk inserting to mysql DB table using perl

Tags: mysql, perl, bulkinsert, dbi, dbd

I am using a simple perl script to pupulate millions of rows in a mysql DB table. I'm using perl DBI and DBD::mysql with the script. Example code below

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(<DB INFO>);
my $sth;
my $insert_com = "INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
for (1..50000000){

   $sth = $dbh->prepare($insert_com);
   $sth->execute(<val1>,<val2>,<val3>,<val4>,<val5>);

}
```

As per the above code, I think a commit is sent for each iteration of the loop.
The question I have is, whether it's possible to send a commit every n iteration ? i.e to commit after inserting n number of rows to the table. If its possible, can someone please tell me how. Thanks in advance. Cheers ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert 20K rows in single insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164070/mysql-insert-20k-rows-in-single-insert)

Comment: Take ` $sth = $dbh->prepare($insert_com);` statement out of loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set then "AutoCommit to zero:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password,
                      { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 });
```

and call all n rows `$dbh->commit()`

See [DBI Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm) for more details.